# Matlab: Meaning of @(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)) from Andrew Ng's Machine Learning class

Tags: matlab

I have the following code in MATLAB:

```
%  Set options for fminunc
options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 400);

%  Run fminunc to obtain the optimal theta
%  This function will return theta and the cost 
[theta, cost] = ...
    fminunc(@(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)), initial_theta, options);
```

My instructor has explained the minimising function like so:

> To specify the actual function we are minimizing, we use a "short-hand"
>   for specifying functions, like `@(t)(costFunction(t, X, y))`. This
>   creates a function, with argument `t`, which calls your `costFunction`. This
>   allows us to wrap the `costFunction` for use with `fminunc`.

I really cannot understand what `@(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)` means. What are the both `t`s are doing? What kind of expression is that?

Comment: [Try reading these](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/pass-a-function-to-another-function.html)

Comment: @il_raffa in your link the anonymous functions does not have arguemnt, but here as you can see we have, it's a bit odd for me

Comment: Perhaps [this can help](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html)

Comment: @il_raffa thanks a lot, I didn't know what to search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Matlab, this is called an **anonymous function**.

Take the following line:

```
f = @(t)( 10*t );
```

Here, we are defining a function `f`, which takes one argument `t`, and returns `10*t`. It can be used by

```
f(5) % returns 50
```

In your case, you are using `fminunc` which takes a function as its first argument, with one parameter to minimise over. This could be called using

```
X = 1; y = 1; % Defining variables which aren't passed into the costFunction
              % but which must exist for the next line to pass them as anything!
f = @(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)); % Explicitly define costFunction as a function of t alone
[theta, cost] = fminunc(f, 0, options);
```

This can be shortened by not defining `f` first, and just calling

```
 [theta, cost] = fminunc(@(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)), 0, options);
```

---

**Further reading**

- As mentioned in the comments, here is a link to [generally parameterising functions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html).
- Specifically, here is a documentation link about [anonymous functions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).

Comment: @wolfie, you show it as being a shortened version. Could you explain why the expression itself has to be like that? In the course, he ran the function like this 

[optTheta, functionVal, exitFlag] = fminunc(@costFunction, initialTheta, options)
where

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to Wolfie's response. I was confused as well and asked a similar question here:
[Understanding fminunc arguments and anonymous functions, function handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44875913/understanding-fminunc-arguments-and-anonymous-functions-function-handlers)

The approach here is one of 3. The problem the anonymous function (1 of the 3 approaches in the link below) solves is that the solver, `fminunc` only optimizes one argument in the function passed to it. The anonymous function `@(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)` is a new function that takes in only one argument, t, and later passes this value to costFunction. You will notice that in the video lecture what was entered was just `@costFunction` and this worked because `costFunction` only took one argument, `theta`.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/passing-extra-parameters.html

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same question. All thanks to the the link provided by Wolfie to understand [paramterized and anonymous functions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html), I was able to clarify my doubts. Perhaps, you must have already found your answer but am explaining once again, for people  who might develop this query in the mere future.

Let's say we want to derive a polynomial, and find its minimum/maximum value. Our code is:

```
m = 5;
fun = @(x) x^2 + m; % function that takes one input: x, accepts 'm' as constant
x = derive(fun, 0); % fun passed as an argument
```

As per the above code, 'fun' is a handle that points to our anonymous function, `f(x)=x^2 + m`. It accepts only one input, i.e. x. The advantage of an anonymous function is, one doesn't need to create a separate program for it. For the constant, 'm', it can accept any values residing in the current [workspace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/workspace.html).

The above code can be shortened by:

```
m = 5;
x = derive(@(x) x^2 + m, 0); % passed the anonymous function directly as argument
```

Answer (score 0):

Our target is to find the global optimal,so i think the function here is to get a bounch of local minimal by change the alpha and compare with each other to see which one is the best.

to achive this you initiate the fminuc with value initial_theta

1. `fminuc set t=initial_theta` then compute `CostFunction(t,X,y)` which is equal to` CostFunction(initial_theta,X,y).you will get the Cost and also the gradient.
2. `fminuc` will compute a `new_theta` with the gradient and a alpha, then set `t=new_theta` and compute the Cost and gradient again.
3. it will loop like this until it find the local optimal.
4. Then it change the length of alpha and repeat above to get another optimal. At the end it will compare the optimals and return with the best one.