# Understanding fminunc arguments and anonymous functions, function handlers

Tags: matlab

Please bear with me. The question is at the end. I am trying to figure out the difference in how fminunc is called.

This question stems from Andrew Ng's Week 3 material in his Coursera Machine Learning course. 
I am bouncing off of this question. [Matlab: Meaning of @(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)) from Andrew Ng's Machine Learning class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43961765/what-is-short-hand-in-matlab)

I am trying to understand the meaning of the argument

```
@(t) ( costFunction(t, X, y) )
```

User wolfie, showed it as being a shortened version. Could anyone explain why the expression itself has to be like that? In the video lecture, he ran the function like this

```
[optTheta, functionVal, exitFlag] = fminunc(@costFunction, initialTheta, options)
```

where `costFunction` inputs and outputs from the program file are given as:

```
function [jVal, gradient] = costFunction(theta)
```

The exercise provided code has this version of the function: 
`costFunction(theta, X, y)`.

Why wasn't fminunc called like in the second case without the anonymous function, that is why was it called as:

`[theta, cost] = fminunc(@(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)), initial_theta, options);`

instead of as:

`[theta, cost] = fminunc(@costFunction, initial_theta, options);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cost function should have the parameter(s) to be optimized as input, and return the function value to be minimized. In case the cost function needs input other than the to-be-optimized parameter(s), the anonymous function form will do the trick:

```
funHandle = @(t) ( costFunction(t, X, y) );
```

This allows you pass extra input *X* and *y*, besides to-be-optimized *t*. You can check 
[this link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/passing-extra-parameters.html) from Mathworks for more information.

Comment: I edited the question as apparently what was shown in the video lectures was the costFunction with the just theta as the argument but what was provided in the exercise was costFunction(theta, X, y). Your answer still pointed me to the right direction and I find it is still correct. The solver fminunc only takes one argument but we have a function that takes in more than one so we define an anonymous function that takes just one argument, t, that we want to optimize with the solver.